# How to use expression in QgsVectorlayer label by using python?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, python-2.7

how to show the two field values as a label on features. I have done it for a field called "ErrorDescr" with this i need to show another field values. Other field is "MarkerId"

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "ErrorDescr")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "2")
```

is it possible to bring the output like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/isExpression", True)
```

and you can use the expression in the string:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "concat(ErrorDescr, Markerid)")
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan Its working fine. How to add a separator like - , / between ErrorDescr and Markerid?

Comment: `concat(ErrorDescr,'-', Markerid)`